# Having problem using ( ) and ? to find the phone number and extension number in a sample text (Regex)(Python)

Tags: python, regex

I am a beginner and I was planning to create a regex to find phone numbers and, if available, the phone extension in a sample text. I am using the option "findall". I had spent some good time trying and changing the code and this what I thought the most effective. I am having a hard time to understand why the terminal is giving these results.

I am not sure what have I missed here. If I remove the extension section it works fine, but as soon as I add it, it can find anything.

```
import re

text = ' This is my number (801)-804-2121 ext 458, my NEW PHONE IS 375-704-5121,work phone is 805.544.2335 and my wifes is 458 8458'

phoneNumberReg = re.compile(r'''  \(?\d{3}\)?
                                  \D{0,3}   #separating
                                  \d{3}
                                  \D{0,3}    #separating
                                  \d{4}
                                  \s*(ext|x|ext.)?
                                  \s*(\d{2,5})?           
                                  ''', re.VERBOSE)

resultsPhone = phoneNumberReg.findall(text)

print(resultsPhone)

Terminal:
['', '', '']
[('ext', '458'), ('', ''), ('', '')]
```

Also, If I make the area code as optional to find number 000-0000, it will only find the first part of the number.

```
(\(?\d{3}\)?)?

Terminal:
['', '', '']
['(801)', '375', '805', '']
```

Comment: First think I will comment is use regex101.com, it'll save you so much time. Just look over the code now.

Comment: The [findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) method returns the *captured groups* (if there are any). Your regexp only includes two capturing groups (for parts of the extension number), so that's all that will appear in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with your example and standardizes the number format for display.  Non-capturing groups (`(?:)`) are added to prevent capture of unnecessary information and capturing groups (`()`) are used to capture the digits.

```py
import re

text = ' This is my number (801)-804-2121 ext 458, my NEW PHONE IS 375-704-5121,work phone is 805.544.2335 and my wifes is 458 8458'

phoneNumberReg = re.compile(r'''(?:\(?(\d{3})\)?[-. ]?)?          # area code optional
                                (\d{3})[-. ]?(\d{4})              # phone number
                                (?:\s*(?:ext\.?|x)\s*(\d{2,5}))?  # extension optional
                                ''', re.VERBOSE)

for m in phoneNumberReg.finditer(text):
    area, prefix, number, ext = m.groups()
    print(f"{f'{area}-' if area else ''}{prefix}-{number}{f' x{ext}' if ext else ''}")
```

Output:

```
801-804-2121 x458
375-704-5121
805-544-2335
458-8458
```

Answer (score 0):

Also best query I could come up with to help you. I don't know anything about python's findall, so can't help with that. You keep interchanging \s with \S which are two completely different things, \s is any white character while \S is any special characters.

Also you weren't backspacing a . in regex, which means any character.

Regex: ((?\d{1,3})?(\s|\S))?(\s|\S)?(\d{3})(\s|\S)?(\d{4})(\s(ext|x|ext.)(\s|\S)?(\d{3}))?